# Escaping %USERPROFILE% Tag in .bat

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

With `%USERPROFILE%` I can get the User's home-directory in the cmd or via a bat-File. But I only get one Backslash `C:\Users\guy` and I need it transformed with an escape Slash.

It should look like `C:\\Users\\guy`

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my machine:

```
echo %USERPROFILE:\=\\%
```

Or as a variable:

```
set a=%USERPROFILE:\=\\%
echo %a%
```

Comment: On my machine too. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "profile=%USERPROFILE:\=\\%"
echo %profile%
```